# Should I use more than one index on the same table when left joining three other tables to it

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, indexing

I am currently using SQL Server 2014 and I have to left join three tables to another table. 
Transaction table containing 1.5 billion records
 Product table containing 1.5 million records
Location table containing 1 millon records
Cost Centre table containing 5000 records
 The tables are joned in following manner:
`SELECT [Transaction].*
       ,[Product].[Product_Description]
       ,[Location].[Location_Description]
       ,[Cost Centre].[Cost_Centre_Description]
INTO [Transaction_Master]
FROM Transaction
    LEFT JOIN [Product] on [Transaction].[Division] = [Product].[Division] AND 
                           [Transaction].[SKU] = [Product].[SKU]
    LEFT JOIN [Location] on [Transaction].[Division] = [Product].[Division] AND 
                            [Transaction].[StoreCode] = [Product].[StoreCode] 
    LEFT JOIN [Cost Centre] on [Transaction].[StoreCode] = [Cost Centre].[StoreCode] 
GO`
 My Question is...Should I create three different indexes on the Transaction table

1. on the [Division],[SKU] fields to join on the Product table
2. on the [Division],[StoreCode] fields to join on the Location table
3. on the [StoreCode] field to join on the Cost Centre table

or would one index be sufficient if I create an index on the [Division], [SKU] and [StoreCode] fields?

Comment: Your query is not complete.  It is missing the last `ON` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your query, you want indexes on all the tables *except* `Transactions`:

- `Product(Division, SKU)`
- `Location(Division, StoreCode)`
- `CostCenter(StoreCode)`

You can also include the `Description` column, depending on its type (or you can include the `Description` as an extra non-key column in the index).

Note that the first two (at least) are composite indexes (multiple columns).  The third only requires a single column.  I would advise you to change your tables to use synthetic primary keys, but that is another matter entirely.

The index on `Transactions` is not necessary because you are doing `LEFT JOIN`s with no filters.  Hence, you need to read the entire table anyway.  The key to performance is getting the values from the other tables.

I should note that such a generic query on a table with 1.5 billion rows is unlikely to be useful.  If you have a `where` clause, then you probably do want filters of some sort.  Also, in a well-designed database, I don't see why `LEFT JOIN` would be necessary.  The values along these dimensions should all be correctly populated.

Comment: i'd include the description fields since they are needed in the output.